# Problems on listing entity as checkbox on Symfony2

Tags: mysql, symfony, checkbox, entity

My system has two related tables called **material** and **items_budget**. The second table has a form that lists the name of each **material** as a `checkbox`, followed by two more `input`, one for its quantity and the other one for its price. Here's the code:

```
{% for material in materials %}
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input class="itemsbudget_material" type="checkbox" name="cdg_itemsbudget_type[material][]" value="{{ material.id }}"> {{ material.name }} - 
        </label>
        <input class="itemsbudget_quantity" type="text" name="cdg_itemsbudget_type[quantity][]" placeholder="Qtd" size="5"/>x - R$
        <input class="itemsbudget_price_hidden" type="hidden" value="{{ material.price }}"/>
        <input class="itemsbudget_price" type="text" name="cdg_itemsbudget_type[price][]" value="0" size="5" readonly/>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

There is a trigger that is triggered when new data is inserted into **items_budget**, which function is to subtract from the current quantity of the selected **material** the quantity specified in the form.

The problems is that the trigger's function only works correctly with the first register in the **material** table, with the rest, the quantity field always returns NULL. According to the code above, I tried to proceed by putting brackets at the end of the `name` attribute, but doing this way the form page is only refreshed and no data is inserted into **items_budget**. Is there another way to list entities in Symfony2? Thank you!

Comment: Where's your backend code?

Comment: Use the symfony formbuilder component with the entity type: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html and set expanded and multiple attribute to true

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this with the Symfony Form component, you need to use a [Form Collection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html). Have a look at the link!

So your items_budget type will contain a collection of material type forms.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('materials', 'collection',  array(
            'type' => new MaterialType()
        ))
    ;
}
```

The MaterialType contains all the form fields that are displayed in each row.

When the form is submitted, you get the ItemsBudget entity with the whole collection of Material entities and you can do with them whatever you want. You can have a boolean property that is rendered as a checkbox and then just check for it's value and do something based on it.

Comment: I couldn't understand the documentation, they lack of explanation. By following this `collection` type, I managed to list all the form, but this is not what I need. I need to list only the `name` of each **material** and add two more `input` fields to enter the `quantity` and `price` of each one, according to the code I wrote. Besides, if in my way the first registers works perfectly, why can't it work with others???

Comment: The idea is that `quantity` and `price` are fields of the materialType. If you also add them to the material entity as properties (no need to make them persistent), symfony handles all the form stuff for you, and you can access all the values like `$budget->getMaterials()[0]->getQuantity();`.

Comment: The **items_budget** table is for registering the selected Material, its quantity and the price. The **material** has only the price, actually.